# Resolve a circular dependency issue in Spring with `sessionFactory` and `transactionManager`

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm using **Hibernate 3.6** and **Spring 3.2**

I seem to have a circular dependency when I start my application.

My `applicationContext.xml` (simplified) looks like so:

```xml
<beans
       xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

  <bean id="wicketApplication"
        class="us.ak.state.revenue.cssd.Personnel.QuickStartApplication" />
  <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="us.ak.state.revenue.cssd.Personnel.utils.SessionFactoryBean" >
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml">
    </property>
    <property name="entityInterceptor">
      <ref bean="interceptor" />
    </property>
  </bean>

  <!-- using Annotations -->
  <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" />

  <!-- setup transaction manager  -->
  <bean id="txManager"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <!--
    <property name="sessionFactory">
      <ref bean="sessionFactory" />
    </property>
    -->
  </bean>

  <bean id="transactionTemplate"
        class="org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="txManager"/>
  </bean>

  <!-- List functions that should be Transactional -->
  <tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="txManager">
    <tx:attributes>
      <tx:method name="find*"     propagation="REQUIRED"/>
      <tx:method name="size*"     propagation="REQUIRED"/>
      <tx:method name="attach*"   propagation="REQUIRED"/>
      <tx:method name="save"      propagation="REQUIRED"/>
      <tx:method name="persist"   propagation="REQUIRED"/>
      <tx:method name="update"    propagation="REQUIRED"/>
      <tx:method name="merge"     propagation="REQUIRED"/>
      <tx:method name="delete"    propagation="REQUIRED"/>
      <tx:method name="onAttach*" propagation="REQUIRED"/>
      <tx:method name="onSave"    propagation="REQUIRED"/>
      <tx:method name="onPersist" propagation="REQUIRED"/>
      <tx:method name="onUpdate"  propagation="REQUIRED"/>
      <tx:method name="onMerge"   propagation="REQUIRED"/>
      <tx:method name="onDelete"  propagation="REQUIRED"/>          
    </tx:attributes>
  </tx:advice>

  <!-- TODO: look into creating a custom interceptor later -->
  <bean id="interceptor" class="org.hibernate.EmptyInterceptor"></bean>

  <bean id="AuditDAO" class="us.ak.state.revenue.cssd.dao.AuditDAO" >
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
  </bean>
  <!-- other DAOs omitted for brevity -->

  <context:component-scan base-package="us.ak.state.revenue.cssd" >
    <context:include-filter type="assignable"
            expression="us.ak.state.revenue.cssd.Personnel.dao.BaseHibernateDAO" />
  </context:component-scan>
</beans>
```

When I try and run my application the following appears in my error log:

```java
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
  at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
  at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:122) 
  at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:105) 
  at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:74)
  at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:312)
  at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211) 
  at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:288) 
  at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
  at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:284)
  at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
  at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:180)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:41)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:173)
  at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
  at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
  at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
  at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:220)
  at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
  at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:115)
  at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:23)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:180)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:41)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:173)
  at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
  at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:220)
  at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
  at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:77) 
  at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:195)
  at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:63)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
  at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
  Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
    Error creating bean with name 'wicketApplication' defined in class path resource [testApplicationContext.xml]: 
      Unsatisfied dependency expressed through bean property 'iAuditDAO': : 
        Error creating bean with name 'AuditDAO' defined in class path resource [testApplicationContext.xml]: 
          Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; 
  nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
    Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [testApplicationContext.xml]: 
      Unsatisfied dependency expressed through bean property 'eventListeners': : 
        Error creating bean with name 'txManager' defined in class path resource [testApplicationContext.xml]: 
          Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory';
  nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: 
    Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': 
      FactoryBean which is currently in creation returned null from getObject; 
  nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
    Error creating bean with name 'txManager' defined in class path resource [testApplicationContext.xml]: 
      Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; 
  nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: 
    Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': FactoryBean which is currently in creation returned null from getObject; 
  nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
    Error creating bean with name 'AuditDAO' defined in class path resource [testApplicationContext.xml]: 
      Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; 
    nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
    Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [testApplicationContext.xml]: 
  Unsatisfied dependency expressed through bean property 'eventListeners': : 
    Error creating bean with name 'txManager' defined in class path resource [testApplicationContext.xml]: 
    Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; 
  nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: 
    Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': 
      FactoryBean which is currently in creation returned null from getObject; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
        Error creating bean with name 'txManager' defined in class path resource [testApplicationContext.xml]: 
          Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; 
  nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: 
    Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': 
      FactoryBean which is currently in creation returned null from getObject
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireByType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1215)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1107)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626)
  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
  at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:120)
  at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
  at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:100) 
  at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:248)
  at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:64)
  at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:91)
  ... 36 more Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
   Error creating bean with name 'AuditDAO' defined in class path resource [testApplicationContext.xml]: 
    Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; 
  nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
    Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [testApplicationContext.xml]: 
      Unsatisfied dependency expressed through bean property 'eventListeners': : 
       Error creating bean with name 'txManager' defined in class path resource [testApplicationContext.xml]: 
         Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; 
  nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: 
    Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': 
      FactoryBean which is currently in creation returned null from getObject; 
  nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
    Error creating bean with name 'txManager' defined in class path resource [testApplicationContext.xml]: 
      Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; 
  nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException:
    Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': 
      FactoryBean which is currently in creation returned null from getObject
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:329)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:107)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1393)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1134)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:910)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:853)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:768)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireByType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1200)  
  ... 52 more Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
    Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [testApplicationContext.xml]: 
    Unsatisfied dependency expressed through bean property 'eventListeners': : 
      Error creating bean with name 'txManager' defined in class path resource [testApplicationContext.xml]: 
        Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; 
  nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: 
  Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': 
    FactoryBean which is currently in creation returned null from getObject; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
      Error creating bean with name 'txManager' defined in class path resource [testApplicationContext.xml]: 
        Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; 
  nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: 
    Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': 
      FactoryBean which is currently in creation returned null from getObject
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireByType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1215)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1107)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:323)
  ... 65 more Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
    Error creating bean with name 'txManager' defined in class path resource [testApplicationContext.xml]: 
      Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; 
  nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: 
    Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': 
      FactoryBean which is currently in creation returned null from getObject
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:329)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:107)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1393)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1134)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:910)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:840)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:768) 
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireByType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1200)  
  ... 73 more Caused by: 
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: 
      Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': 
        FactoryBean which is currently in creation returned null from getObject
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:156)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:109)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1448)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:249)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:323)
  ... 86 more
```

So how can I correct my `applicationContext.xml` to correct the error?

**UPDATE:**
Per @kaviddiss suggestion I'm adding details about `SessionFactoryBean`
`public class SessionFactoryBean extends LocalSessionFactoryBean`  All it does is
`@Override` `newConfiguration()` to check the server its running on and set the DB Connection String and Logging Levels(debug vs info).

I thought I had taken autowiring out of `<beans ...>` do I need to explicitly set it to off/disabled?

Comment: Its still not working but seeing as I've solved this issue I figured the next step was better as a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16907454/nullpointerexception-in-hibernatedaosupport-getsession

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the xml configuration you also have autowiring configured and these two may create the circular dependency. The stack is referring to bean property eventListener that may cause the problem. You may want to include more details on the us.ak.state.revenue.cssd.Personnel.utils.SessionFactoryBean class for more help. You could also try commenting out some sections of the XML config and/or some of the autowiring annotations until you figure out how to break the circular dependency.

Comment: I had `@Autowired` for a property on my test class.  removing the annotation and the `context:component-scan` successfuly got me to troubleshooting the next issue.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the Hibernate entity interceptor configuration from your XML. It is probably being picked up by the TX AOP, thus causing circular dependencies (via `txManager`).

Later when you will create your own interceptor, don't forget to add `AopInfrastructureBean` interface so that it will not be a subject of AOP wrapping.

---

**UPDATE** I've just realized that there is no pointcut definition in the XML and `<tx:annotation-driven>` is being used (i.e. AOP is based on `@Transactional` annotations). This means that my answer can not be correct.

Comment: I must be missing something I only want `tx:advice` to operate on the `beans` that have a `sessionFactory`. Is that not what its doing?

Comment: I've made a mistake when reading your config. You have configured just TX advice, not pointcut. And it seems that this advice must ignored as you are using annotation-driven TX management.

Comment: Then you need to drop the `<tx:annotation-driven>` as well.