# NullPointerException in HibernateDaoSupport.getSession()

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, wicket

I'm using **Wicket-1.5.x**, **Spring-3.2**, and **Hibernate-3.6**.  My application successfully starts and reads from the database, however when I try to actually load a page I get the exception pasted below.

Why can't it find the session?  From what I can tell its not even the dreaded `LazyLoadInitializationException` so I'm not even sure where to begin, I'm not sure its gotten far enough in the page render process to tell whether or not if OpenSessionInViewFilter would even have helped.

```
org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: Exception in rendering component: [TooltipContainer [Component id = firstNameTip]]
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRenderComponent(Component.java:2590)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onRender(MarkupContainer.java:1530)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRender(Component.java:2393)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.render(Component.java:2321)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderNext(MarkupContainer.java:1428)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderAll(MarkupContainer.java:1592)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderComponentTagBody(MarkupContainer.java:1567)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onComponentTagBody(MarkupContainer.java:1521)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.onComponentTagBody(Form.java:1656)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.panel.DefaultMarkupSourcingStrategy.onComponentTagBody(DefaultMarkupSourcingStrategy.java:72)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRenderComponent(Component.java:2563)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onRender(MarkupContainer.java:1530)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRender(Component.java:2393)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.render(Component.java:2321)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderNext(MarkupContainer.java:1428)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderAll(MarkupContainer.java:1592)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderComponentTagBody(MarkupContainer.java:1567)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onComponentTagBody(MarkupContainer.java:1521)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.panel.DefaultMarkupSourcingStrategy.onComponentTagBody(DefaultMarkupSourcingStrategy.java:72)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRenderComponent(Component.java:2563)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onRender(MarkupContainer.java:1530)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRender(Component.java:2393)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.render(Component.java:2321)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderNext(MarkupContainer.java:1428)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderAll(MarkupContainer.java:1592)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderComponentTagBody(MarkupContainer.java:1567)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onComponentTagBody(MarkupContainer.java:1521)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.panel.DefaultMarkupSourcingStrategy.onComponentTagBody(DefaultMarkupSourcingStrategy.java:72)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRenderComponent(Component.java:2563)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onRender(MarkupContainer.java:1530)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRender(Component.java:2393)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.render(Component.java:2321)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderNext(MarkupContainer.java:1428)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderAll(MarkupContainer.java:1592)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderComponentTagBody(MarkupContainer.java:1567)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onComponentTagBody(MarkupContainer.java:1521)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.panel.DefaultMarkupSourcingStrategy.onComponentTagBody(DefaultMarkupSourcingStrategy.java:72)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRenderComponent(Component.java:2563)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onRender(MarkupContainer.java:1530)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRender(Component.java:2393)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.render(Component.java:2321)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderNext(MarkupContainer.java:1428)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderAll(MarkupContainer.java:1592)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderComponentTagBody(MarkupContainer.java:1567)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onComponentTagBody(MarkupContainer.java:1521)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.panel.DefaultMarkupSourcingStrategy.onComponentTagBody(DefaultMarkupSourcingStrategy.java:72)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRenderComponent(Component.java:2563)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onRender(MarkupContainer.java:1530)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRender(Component.java:2393)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.render(Component.java:2321)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderNext(MarkupContainer.java:1428)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderAll(MarkupContainer.java:1592)
    at org.apache.wicket.Page.onRender(Page.java:907)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.WebPage.onRender(WebPage.java:140)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRender(Component.java:2393)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.render(Component.java:2321)
    at org.apache.wicket.Page.renderPage(Page.java:1035)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.WebPageRenderer.renderPage(WebPageRenderer.java:118)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.WebPageRenderer.respond(WebPageRenderer.java:246)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.RenderPageRequestHandler.respond(RenderPageRequestHandler.java:167)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle$HandlerExecutor.respond(RequestCycle.java:784)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.RequestHandlerStack.execute(RequestHandlerStack.java:64)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.execute(RequestCycle.java:255)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequest(RequestCycle.java:212)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequestAndDetach(RequestCycle.java:283)
    at org.apache.wicket.util.tester.BaseWicketTester.processRequest(BaseWicketTester.java:696)
    at org.apache.wicket.util.tester.BaseWicketTester.processRequest(BaseWicketTester.java:624)
    at org.apache.wicket.util.tester.BaseWicketTester.processRequest(BaseWicketTester.java:596)
    at org.apache.wicket.util.tester.BaseWicketTester.startPage(BaseWicketTester.java:1257)
    at org.apache.wicket.util.tester.BaseWicketTester.startPage(BaseWicketTester.java:1230)
    at us.ak.state.revenue.cssd.Personnel.Pages.MaintenanceForms.Employee.TestChangeRequestMaintenance.__CLR3_1_11lo23k3ciu(TestChangeRequestMaintenance.java:52)
    at us.ak.state.revenue.cssd.Personnel.Pages.MaintenanceForms.Employee.TestChangeRequestMaintenance.testLoadPageLoggedIn_DO(TestChangeRequestMaintenance.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:180)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:41)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:173)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:220)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:77)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:195)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while getting the model object for Component: [TextField [Component id = firstName, page = us.ak.state.revenue.cssd.Personnel.Pages.MaintenanceForms.Employee.ChangeRequestMaint, path = 0:emp_info_maint:firstNameTip:firstName.TextField, isVisible = true, isVersioned = false, markup = [markup = file:/C:/Users/tfburton/Documents/JavaProjects/SVN/Personnel/trunk/target/classes/us/ak/state/revenue/cssd/Personnel/Pages/MaintenanceForms/Employee/ChangeRequestMaint.html
<input wicket:id="firstName" type="text" class="noChange"/>, index = 0, current =  '<input wicket:id="firstName" type="text" class="noChange"/>' (line 0, column 0)]]]
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.getDefaultModelObject(Component.java:1679)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.getDefaultModelObjectAsString(Component.java:1701)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.FormComponent.getModelValue(FormComponent.java:1211)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.FormComponent.getValue(FormComponent.java:837)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.TextField.onComponentTag(TextField.java:108)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRenderComponent(Component.java:2534)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onRender(MarkupContainer.java:1530)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRender(Component.java:2393)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.render(Component.java:2321)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderNext(MarkupContainer.java:1428)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderAll(MarkupContainer.java:1592)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderComponentTagBody(MarkupContainer.java:1567)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onComponentTagBody(MarkupContainer.java:1521)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.panel.DefaultMarkupSourcingStrategy.onComponentTagBody(DefaultMarkupSourcingStrategy.java:72)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRenderComponent(Component.java:2563)
    ... 104 more
Caused by: org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: Error calling method: public java.lang.String us.ak.state.revenue.cssd.Personnel.dao.Employee.Employee.getFirstName() on object: null
    at org.apache.wicket.util.lang.PropertyResolver$MethodGetAndSet.getValue(PropertyResolver.java:1127)
    at org.apache.wicket.util.lang.PropertyResolver$ObjectAndGetSetter.getValue(PropertyResolver.java:648)
    at org.apache.wicket.util.lang.PropertyResolver.getValue(PropertyResolver.java:102)
    at org.apache.wicket.model.AbstractPropertyModel.getObject(AbstractPropertyModel.java:134)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.getDefaultModelObject(Component.java:1674)
    ... 118 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport.getSession(HibernateDaoSupport.java:143)
    at us.ak.state.revenue.cssd.Personnel.dao.NameTableHome.findByPcn(NameTableHome.java:555)
    at WICKET_us.ak.state.revenue.cssd.Personnel.dao.NameTableHome$$FastClassByCGLIB$$bd58bb2e.invoke(<generated>)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:191)
    at org.apache.wicket.proxy.LazyInitProxyFactory$CGLibInterceptor.intercept(LazyInitProxyFactory.java:333)
    at WICKET_us.ak.state.revenue.cssd.Personnel.dao.NameTableHome$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$e12a569d.findByPcn(<generated>)
    at us.ak.state.revenue.cssd.Personnel.dao.PcnTable.getNameTable(PcnTable.java:198)
    at us.ak.state.revenue.cssd.Personnel.dao.Employee.Employee.getNameTable(Employee.java:697)
    at us.ak.state.revenue.cssd.Personnel.dao.Employee.Employee.getFirstName(Employee.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at org.apache.wicket.util.lang.PropertyResolver$MethodGetAndSet.getValue(PropertyResolver
```

**UPDATE**

My Test Classes extend the following class:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:testApplicationContext.xml" })
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager = "txManager")
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public abstract class AbstractWebPageTests implements ApplicationContextAware
```

I'm using annotations to wire up my Test classes. But I'm trying to stick to using XML as much as possible to wire-up my actual Web Application which gets loaded via `new WicketTester(new MockLoggedInApplication(user));` at the beginning of my tests. `MockLoggedInApplication extends QuickstartApplication` and my application does a lot of database reads inside of `QuickStartApplication.init()`.

should I paste my `applicationContext.xml`?

**NOTE:**

I think I've narrowed down the problem.

If you look closely at the bottom `Caused By:`

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport.getSession(HibernateDaoSupport.java:143)
    at us.ak.state.revenue.cssd.Personnel.dao.NameTableHome.findByPcn(NameTableHome.java:555)
    at WICKET_us.ak.state.revenue.cssd.Personnel.dao.NameTableHome$$FastClassByCGLIB$$bd58bb2e.invoke(<generated>)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:191)
    at org.apache.wicket.proxy.LazyInitProxyFactory$CGLibInterceptor.intercept(LazyInitProxyFactory.java:333)
    at WICKET_us.ak.state.revenue.cssd.Personnel.dao.NameTableHome$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$e12a569d.findByPcn(<generated>)
    at us.ak.state.revenue.cssd.Personnel.dao.PcnTable.getNameTable(PcnTable.java:198)
    at us.ak.state.revenue.cssd.Personnel.dao.Employee.Employee.getNameTable(Employee.java:697)
    at us.ak.state.revenue.cssd.Personnel.dao.Employee.Employee.getFirstName(Employee.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at org.apache.wicket.util.lang.PropertyResolver$MethodGetAndSet.getValue(PropertyResolver
```

My DAO is *processed* by my Wicket proxy `WICKET_us.ak.state.revenue.cssd.Personnel.dao.NameTableHome$$FastClassByCGLIB$$bd58bb2e.invoke(<generated>)`.  However, even though wicket proxies it for me it never appears to get grabbed by Springs Transaction Management.

My Transaction Management config:

```xml
<bean id="sessionFactory"
      class="us.ak.state.revenue.cssd.Personnel.utils.SessionFactoryBean" >
  <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml">
  </property>
</bean>

<bean id="txManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
  <property name="sessionFactory">
    <ref bean="sessionFactory" />
  </property>
</bean>

<tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="txManager">
    <tx:attributes>
      <tx:method name="find*"     propagation="REQUIRED"/>
      <!-- others omitted for brevity -->
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>

<aop:config proxy-target-class="true" >
     <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice"
          pointcut="execution(* *..BaseHibernateDAO+.find*(..))" />
     <!-- omitted for brevity -->
</aop:config> 

<bean id="NameTableHome"
      class="us.ak.state.revenue.cssd.Personnel.dao.NameTableHome" >
  <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>
<!-- other dao beans omitted for brevity -->
```

`NameTableHome` is declared similar to this:

```
public class NameTableHome extends BaseHibernateDAO
```

Comment: Nowadays, use of `HibernateDaoSupport` is not recomended. http://stackoverflow.com/a/5104965/870248

Comment: This code originally used **Spring-2.5.x**  I've upgraded to **3.2** thanks for the note I'll look into converting my base class once I get my application working again.

Comment: It looks like the NPE happens when it's getting the session.  I would look into the configuration to see if the SessionFactory is not getting created or set.  I would expect that it would fail coming up though, unless you are using Annotations to wire things together and for whatever reason the thing wiring the SessionFactory into the HibernateDAOSupport has it set to required=false.

Answer (score 0):

Based upon the code at HibernateDaoSupport:143 (at least in my version, spring-orm 3.2.2) I suspect the field hibernateTemplate of HibernateDaoSupport is null. Are you sure the template is being set properly?